# Postgres диапазон чисел?

Tags: postgresql

подскажите как правильно записать диапазон в базу?
предположим

```
значение значение 2
10-20         12
20-30         16
```

понятно что писать видать придется как текст. а потом как с этим работать?

Comment: А почему нельзя разбить диапазон на две колонки и хранить границы отдельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря, в PostgreSQL есть готовый (и расширяемый) тип данных - [range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html). Это не то, что вы ищете?